# How to access non static method of form1 from form2

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to call a function `update` in form1 on click even of button in form2. The update method will make changes to controls in form1. I am using this approach , but when I access it does not give access( when method is non static ) and when I make the method static it asks to make the controls static too which I don't want to. Is there any other way ?

```
public button1_click()
{

Form1.update();

}

// method in form1

public static void update()
{

 control.Text="ab";

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access non-static variables in static methods. Refer to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx):

> While an instance of a class contains a separate copy of all instance fields of the class, there is only one copy of each static field.
>
> It is not possible to use this to reference static methods or property accessors.

In this case, if your `update` method (BTW should be `Update`) needs to access non-static members of your class, you should make it non-static, and change the `Form2` as follows:

1) Add a field and change form's constructor to accept `Form1` instance as a parameter:

```
private Form1 form1;

public Form2(Form1 form1)
{
    this.form1 = form1;
}
```

2) When creating `form2` from `form1` pass its instance:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this); // when in Form1
```

If you're creating `Form2` in some other context you need to (analogically) have `form1` instance at hand and call:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(form1);
```

3) Change the event handler to work on the particular instance of `Form1`:

```
public button1_click()
{
    this.form1.update();
}
```